# merge the top 100 rows of multiple CSV's

Tags: csv, merge, split

I have 4000 CSV's each with a random amount of rows ranging from 5 to 10,000. All the columns are the same and the data is ordered in the correct order I need. What I need to to is grab the first 100 rows of every CSV and combine in into 1 CSV file.

Does anyone know of any software or script that would be able to manage this? I am a windows user with basic knowledge of command prompt.

Any help much appeciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bash script like the following.
I'm supposing all the files are in current directory:

```
> destination_file.csv
for f in *.csv; do
  head -n 100 $f >> destination_file.csv
done
```

This is just a skeleton but it basically does what you expect.